# define cell width based on the longest content in html

Tags: css, html-table

want the width of all the cells of the table to be as long as it takes to contain the longest content without "creating" a new line indirectly. Smaller words shall be placed to the center of the corresponding cell. For example take this code

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>      
        <td>First name</td>
        <td>Hire dataς</td>
        <td>A really really long word</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It has a fixed width. I want the width to be equal with the length of "A really really long word". The width of the cells will be larger. The rest tr_s will be aligned to left I want them aligned in the center. I wish I could describe it more accurately.Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Post your coding. Explain in more detail what you would like to achieve.

Comment: @ImagineStudios I edited the post. Hope that helps.

Comment: You want all the cells to have the same length? or you want them to be as long as needed to keep all the words in one line?

Comment: @ImagineStudios I want all the cells to have width X where X = the width of cell  that contains the "A really really long word"

Comment: So you want all of the cells to be 300px?

Comment: Do you want all cells to be on the same line or [like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/QFeSG/2/)

Comment: @ImagineStudios Same line. The string "A really really long word" is just an example. The max string can be anywhere at the table.

Comment: The requirements are obscure and seem to be self-contradictory, making all cells have the width needed for some text on one line *and* to remain within 300px. What if that some text is the content of the Bible and the font size is 100px?

Comment: I don't want it to remain fixed at 300px. It was an example. I removed it. It's not gonna be that long. I just want, somehow, to scan the row, find the longest content and make all the cells have that width. Is it really that hard? :O

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_nowrap

Then you can use CSS to make the table text centered, via inline if you're not using a seperate stylesheet

```
<td nowrap style="text-align: center"> content </td>
```

Comment: I think it should affect the whole <tr>.

Comment: Just read your comment "I don't want it to remain fixed at 300px. It was an example. I removed it. It's not gonna be that long. I just want, somehow, to scan the row, find the longest content and make all the cells have that width. Is it really that hard?"

And have to agree, this is actually outside the scope of what HTML and CSS can do as the basic issue is that the cell that has the biggest width at random isn't being told to do what it is doing, it is simply following the rules of the DOM. Sorry to have to tell you...